# Fetching only specified list of attributes for elements selected through element selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fetch first 10 `<p>`elements in a document which I can easily do using `$('p').slice(0,10)`. But going further I want to get only few attributes for each of the element returned by above call. For eg. when I execute `$('p')` in my script, I get each element with attributes such as `childnodes, classname, firstchild, innerText, innerHTML` etc.. I am interested in only the `innertext and few others`. Is there a way I can specify the list of attributes which I want to fetch for each of the elements selected?

Comment: Why can't you just ignore them? Just because they're there doesn't mean you have to use them.

Comment: I need to use this as array to process later. If I cannot select the attributes here, I will need to loop through the elements and create own array later with only the selected properties.

Comment: That is indeed what you'll have to do. I've posted an answer with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The objects returned by jQuery selections are wrappers of DOM `Node` objects, which will always have those properties. You can't retrieve just the properties that you need directly from selecting elements.

If you need to create transport objects containing only specific properties, you will need to create them separately using the properties you want from the `Node` objects:

```
var elements = [];

$('p').slice(0, 10).each(function() {
  elements.push({
    tagName: this.tagName, 
    innerText: this.innerText, 
    className: this.className
  });
});
```